# Some css @keyframes animation opacity issues

Tags: css

Can anybody explain why this code doesn't hide elemens between 95-100%? I want to show hidden by opacity object and hide it after animation. I have no idea why it doesn't work.

```css
button {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: button 6s linear infinite 0s;
}

@keyframes button {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(64px);
 }
 5% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
 }
  95% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>example</button>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably in a [stack snippet](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/9253414).

Comment: It will not hide but will *fade*. The element will be hidden only at 100%

Comment: @TemaniAfif well it doesn't fadeOut.

Comment: it does, but you need to wait 36s. I made it smaller so you can better see

Comment: @TemaniAfif seems like attention has let me down. Thank you!

Comment: As the animation is `infinite` it shows button repeatedly.